# ASP.NET MVC: Values sent by jQuery ajax is not being bound to the view model by the action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I cannot explain why the parameters I'm sending to the controller is always null. Here's my AJAX call:

```
var contactViewModel = { "CustCompId": _custCompId, "SuppID": 0 };

$.ajax({
         async: false,
         type: 'POST',
         data: JSON.stringify(contactViewModel),
         url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "GetContacts",
         success: function (result) {
                  contactData = result;
         }                           
  });
```

This is the action that the parameters are supposed to be posted to

```
public JsonResult GetContacts(SuppOrCustViewModel contactViewModel)
{
   //CustCompId and SuppID are always null
}
```

And this is how I defined the **SuppOrCustViewModel**

```
public class SuppOrCustViewModel
{
    public int? CustCompId { get; set; }
    public int? SuppID { get; set; }
}
```

When I put a break point to GetContacts, both properties inside contactViewModel are null. Any reason for that? Looking at what the browser sent, this is what I see: `{"CustCompId":4,"SuppID":0}:`

Thank for helping.

Comment: Same result if you skip the stringify?

Comment: @Mackan Now it's working. Maybe my question should have been `when to use JSON.stringify()?`. In a similar situation, I spent quite a lot of time trying to make it work, until someone suggest I use `JSON.stringify()`. Today, I spent the same amount of time until you suggest that I skip the method.  Can u explain when to use it and when not? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the more I think about this the more I get the feeling that my previous answer was wrong. So I'm revising my statement:

This is most likely an issue with the lack of ajax `contentTypes`. Removing the stringify forces the model binder to see it as a `key/value` pair, and work as expected. Stringifying it, without setting the correct contentType, will treat the entire object as a key (with no value).

I did the below tests (going full out here).

How you sent it (stingifying without contentType):

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(contactViewModel),
     url: "/echo/json/",
     success: function (result) {
         console.log(result);
     }                           
});
```

When inspecting what was actually sent:

[image]

How I first suggested (not stingifying, i.e. sending as key/value pair):

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'POST',
     data: contactViewModel,
     url: "/echo/json/",
     success: function (result) {
              console.log(result);
     }                           
});
```

This works, and MVC can bind it properly. When inspecting what was actually sent:

[image]

And finally, how it probably should have been sent (stringifyed with contentType):

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(contactViewModel),
     url: "/echo/json/",
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     success: function (result) {
              console.log(result);
     }                           
});
```

When inspecting what was actually sent:

[image]

So, using contentType together with stringify is very important. There is also a possibility that your nullable int's will cause issues (it has been known to cause problems in model binding), but I'm sure you'll be able to sort that out.